# Building a mysqli query with order by and per page to show

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, mysqli

The page display all results, now I want to filter results and how many results per page. To do this the visitor use a simple html GET form to select the filter.

Now I get the GET form and try to filter the results

```
<?php
$order_by = mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_GET['order_by']);
$order = if(empty($order_by)){echo 'manufacturer';}else{echo '$order_by';
?>
```

OK now we get the filter and try to get results from MySQL like this

```
$set_order=mysqli_query($database,"SELECT * FROM `products` order by `$order` ASC");}
```

But I get error in the line:

```
   $order = if(empty($order_by)){echo 'manufacturer';}else{echo '$order_by';
```

Cannot find a way to do this ... Any idea?

Comment: `echo` doesn't return a value so why assign a variable to it like that..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set a default value for order by.

```
$order = 'manufacturer';
```

Next, if the user has provided something else, replace the default value with that.

```
if (!empty($_GET['order_by'])) {
    $order = mysqli_real_escape_string($database, $_GET['order_by']);
}
```

Then you can use whatever it ends up being in your query.

```
$set_order = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM `products` order by `$order` ASC");
```

It is definitely good that you're using `mysqli_real_escape_string` here, but I would recommend checking the user input against a list of acceptable column names to mitigate the SQL injection risk.

Answer (score 1):

using single quotes around a variable will not work - but why not assign the variable and then echo it back?

```
$order = empty($order_by) ? 'manufacturer' : $order_by;
echo $order;
```

if however this is to be used in the sql query you do not need to echo it.

After a short 8r break for sleep you have an answer but I'll post this here too.

```
$order = empty($order_by) ? 'manufacturer' : $order_by;
$sql="select * from `products` order by `{$order}` asc;";

$set_order=mysqli_query( $database, $sql );
if( $set_order ){
    /* process recordset */
}
```

Comment: How to do this without echo it and making the query direct?

Comment: Please help me Raider

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(empty($order_by)){$order = 'manufacturer';}else{$order = $order_by;}
```