# HTML Form Select default value from PHP Echo _Post

Tags: php, mysql

I have a html form where people select to filter the mysql results, example

```
<select name="display"> 
<option  value="9999" selected>Display all results</option>
<option  value="10">10 results only</option>
<option  value="20">20 results only</option>
<option  value="50">50 results only</option>
<option  value="100">100 results only</option>
</select>
```

But if people select lets say 50 results per page, after form submit I want the option 50 results only to get marked as selected like this

```
<option  value="50" selected>50 results only</option>
```

The question is How to do this using PHP POST or GET from the form

Comment: you have too many tags here for one thing. Plus, the answer is simple; you assign a variable to a POST/GET array and put it in your query. in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38668132/building-a-mysqli-query-with-order-by-and-per-page-to-show just do the same thing; but use it for your LIMIT, *easy as pie.*

Comment: post your full form.

Comment: you tagged as mysql and mysqli and pdo so your question's unclear. However, you can see what I posted below. that's the best I can offer, given what you posted. @Liberator

Comment: @Liberator I noticed "after" that your question was a "2-part" question. TBH, I'm quite tired right now (it's late here) and overlooked it. I've made an edit to my answer below so you'll need to reload it. I have to go now. If that helps, great. If not, then you'll need to place a comment (and possibly ping me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, assign a variable to a POST array and set it in your LIMIT in the query.

```
// you can also use isset instead of empty here and GET instead of POST
if(!empty($_POST['display'])) {
    $limit = (int)$_POST['display']; // ensure the value is an integer
}
```

Then place the `$limit` variable in your query for LIMIT.

I.e.: (and as basic MySQL)

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM TABLE WHERE col_x = 'xxx' LIMIT $limit
```

The question though is a bit unclear so there isn't much else I can add to this.

Sidenote: LIMIT (with SELECT) accepts additional parameters. I.e.: `LIMIT 0, 50`

```
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

---

**Edit:**

> *"after form submit I want the option 50 results only to get marked as selected"*

In order to keep the value selected, use a conditional statement in the select's options and check if it equals to something:

Sidenote: This will only work if your entire code is inside the same file.

```
<?php   

    if(!empty($_POST['display'])) {
        $limit = $_POST['display'];
        $selected = 'selected';
    }

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="display"> 
    <option  value="9999" <?php if(isset($selected) && $limit==9999 ) {echo $selected; } ?>>Display all results</option>
    <option  value="10" <?php if(isset($selected) && $limit==10) {echo $selected; } ?>>10 results only</option>
    <option  value="20" <?php if(isset($selected) && $limit==20){echo $selected; } ?>>20 results only</option>
    <option  value="50" <?php if(isset($selected) && $limit==50){echo $selected; } ?>>50 results only</option>
    <option  value="100" <?php if(isset($selected) && $limit==100){echo $selected; } ?>>100 results only</option>
    </select>

<input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

You can add in the rest of your code.

Comment: OP: *"after form submit I want the option 50 results only to get marked as selected like this:* - It's late and I'm quite tired and overlooked that.